# Не видно локальную переменную в if Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу программу с `tkinter`, сделала кнопку, которая должна считать расход топлива, в зависимости от значения из `Combobox`. При печати текста происходит ошибка `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pacx_benz' referenced before assignment`. Как это исправить? При удалении `if` все исправно работает, но это мне нужно. (я чайник)

```
def butclick():
  try:
    nach = int(nach_var.get())
    benz = int(benz_var.get())
    ost = int(ost_var.get())
    if benz_var.get() == 'бензин':
        pacx_benz = int(nach + benz - ost)
    elif benz_var.get() == 'дизельное топливо':
        pacx_diz = int(nach + benz - ost)
  except:
     pass

  if (int(ost)) > ((int(nach) + int(benz))) :
     pass #контроль
  else:
      n="\n"
      text.insert(END, n)
      b = '\n' + "Фактический расход товара(бензин): " + str(pacx_benz)
      text.insert(END, b)
      d = '\n' + "Фактический расход товара(дизель): " + str(pacx_diz)
      text.insert(END, d)
```

Comment: скорее всего происходит ошибка в `try` задайте переменные `pacx_benz` и др. выше до `try`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
def butclick():
  ost = 0
  nach = 0
  benz = 0

  try:
    nach = int(nach_var.get())
    benz = int(benz_var.get())
    ost = int(ost_var.get())
    if benz_var.get() == 'бензин':
        pacx_benz = int(nach + benz - ost)
    elif benz_var.get() == 'дизельное топливо':
        pacx_diz = int(nach + benz - ost)
  except:
     pass

  if (int(ost)) > ((int(nach) + int(benz))) :
     pass #контроль
  else:
      n="\n"
      text.insert(END, n)
      b = '\n' + "Фактический расход товара(бензин): " + str(pacx_benz)
      text.insert(END, b)
      d = '\n' + "Фактический расход товара(дизель): " + str(pacx_diz)
      text.insert(END, d)
```

В этом коде я объявил переменные `ost`, `nach`, и `benz` до блока `if`.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от вида топлива вы присваиваете значение или `pacx_benz`, или `pacx_diz`, и одна из этих переменных в любом случае будет не определена. Однако позднее выводите обе эти переменные. Или измените вывод - только расход бензина или только расход дизеля. Или присваивайте значение обеим переменным в самом начале.